# R - nested, self-referencing conditional, aggregate assignment using inline/vector syntax

Tags: r, nested, aggregate-functions, conditional-statements, self-reference

*** update**  I am a little surprised that out of 53 views that I have not heard much. My original thinking was that this must be a fairly common need. I would really appreciate any feedback in terms of either
1) the nature of a referencing a table of which I am making a modification as well
2) why this is not more common or any other insights
3) if my posting lacks clarity or confusing in any way.
Thanks for any direction.
 **end update ***

I'm not too sure what to call this other than "a nested self-referencing aggregate assignment".

1. I will essentially by processing a subset of a subset - the 2nd of which is defined by a condition in the row being processed.
2. the first subset can be blocked by data table KEYS (which I just discovered can speed processing up significantly.)
3. I am looking for the sum of a column in the child subset.
4. which has a condition based on the row being processed.
5. Really - it could be considered three tier (?)

   - The parent data frame/table
   - the block (1st subset)
   - the conditionally dynamic subset
6. A simplified example of the data might look like:

> ```
>   set_num respd_num opt_num            r6 r_rank            g1
>         1     10002       1 -0.2105112116      1 -0.8382152438
>         1     10002       2 -0.0390887667      7  0.0140819481
>         1     10002       3  0.0657098525     10  0.0657098525
>         1     10002       4 -0.0515756431      6 -0.0374936950
>         1     10002       5 -0.2010318437      2 -0.6277040322
>         1     10002       6 -0.1320728396      4 -0.2512542469
>         1     10002       7 -0.1754179416      3 -0.4266721885
>         1     10002       9 -0.0192308747      8  0.0531707148
>         1     10002      10 -0.0816877122      5 -0.1191814073
>         1     10002      11  0.0066917370      9  0.0724015895
> ```

I am looking to calculate (and assign) `g1` which is equal to the `sum(r6)` for items in this subset of items where the r_rank >= that of the row being processed.

Speed is important as the function that uses this code will be called by OPTIM.

Here is the sqldf code. I have tried doing things with data.table .SD and go it to work on the ranking part and it was just too slow to even let finish. I've tried doing things with `lapply`.  Here is rank calculation which work extremely well. However, I am not able to modify it as needed for this challenge.

```
tbl_all_data <- tbl_all_data[,r_rank:=rank(r6),by=key(tbl_all_data)]
```

This, the nested, self-referencing, sum task is probably the most challenging for me in that it is the most time intensive of the many pieces that make up this function/model.

```
f_new <- sqldf("select *,
                      (select sum(r6) 
                      from df t2  
                      where 
                      t2.set_num = t1.set_num and 
                      t2.resp_id = t1.resp_id and
                      t2.r_rank >= t1.r_rank
                      ) as g1                    
                 from df t1
                 ORDER BY t1.set_num, t1.opt_num")
```

I need an extremely fast, and an moderately easy to implement (i.e. not writing it in C) solution and would appreciate any positive direction.

*** Update ***
If I were to process in a loop, I could duplicate a df or dt and...

```
i = 3
for (i in 1:nrow(dt1)) {
   print(i)
   dt1[i,test:=dt2[set_num==dt1[i,set_num] & respd_num==dt1[i,respd_num] & r6<dt1[i,r6],sum(r6)]]
}
```

But this takes a massively long time.

I can get partially there by using data table syntax:

```
new_df <- dt1[,sum(r6),by=list(set_num,respd_num)]
```

How would I handle the conditional for r6 - the last condition of the 3:

I have tried the following. Neither of which return valid values for which I am looking, but may give you an idea of what I am trying to do:

```
new_df <- dt1[,sum(r6<dt1[,r6]),by=list(set_num,respd_num)]
new_df <- dt1[r6<dt1[,r6],sum(r6),by=list(set_num,respd_num)]]
```

Thx...

Comment: Maybe there is a formatting issue on the page which I am not seeing.  
r6 is the column beginning with values 0.903219719.  
If you are assessing that r6 is an integer from some other (unintended) indicator please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to have understood your computation. I've this that correctly computes g1 for the first group, but I can not figure out why for instance the last g1 is 0.903220
and not 0.94894587.

```
s <- 'set_num respd_num   opt_num   r6            r_rank  g1
1       1002        1         0.903219719   1       0.000000
1       1002        2         0.411544925   4       2.460055
1       1002        3         0.770223176   3       1.689832
1       1002        4         0.786611795   2       0.903220
2       1002        1         0.485307389   3       1.689832
2       1002        2         0.94894587    1       0.000000
2       1002        3         0.430522339   4       2.460055
2       1002        4         0.705036633   2       0.903220'

library(plyr)
df <- read.table(text=s, header=TRUE)

ddply(df, c('set_num', 'respd_num'), function(x) {
    oo <- order(x$r_rank)
    g2 <- Reduce(.Primitive("+"), x$r6[oo], init=0, accumulate=TRUE)
    x$g2 <- g2[order(oo)]
    x
  })
```

output:

```
  set_num respd_num opt_num        r6 r_rank       g1        g2
1       1      1002       1 0.9032197      1 0.000000 0.0000000
2       1      1002       2 0.4115449      4 2.460055 2.4600547
3       1      1002       3 0.7702232      3 1.689832 1.6898315
4       1      1002       4 0.7866118      2 0.903220 0.9032197
5       2      1002       1 0.4853074      3 1.689832 1.6539825
6       2      1002       2 0.9489459      1 0.000000 0.0000000
7       2      1002       3 0.4305223      4 2.460055 2.1392899
8       2      1002       4 0.7050366      2 0.903220 0.9489459
```

Comment: Thank you Karl. Much appreciated. I will look at this tonight and test.

Comment: Karl, I had some debugging in my code to fix the values of my g1. And to honest, not sure what happened, but my sqldf code is running much faster. It is still a bottleneck for me, which I have a nagging feeling there is some way to use data tables to speed this up. Here are the results from my sqldf code:

Comment: Just to be thorough - your code ran in about 8 seconds the sqldf is down to .45; which is still a bottle neck for me but I'm out of the woods for the time. Thanks again.

Comment: can your confirm that my results are correct and there's a bug in your example ?

Comment: The bug was in calculating r6 - not this sqldf code. I have updated the sample data to reflect an entire data segment (block?) and updated r6 values. In the previous sample data your code came close, but not exact in most lines. Your using my updated values And in you above example there seems to be a progressive movement away from my values - some being close, but not exact and diverging. Now results from your code don't seem to come close to mine at all. And your code seems modify the rank value. What is the best to share results or a test script?

Comment: Apologize for the typos. Quick Take - with  my updated values your code does not get me close (which I don't get); and in the original scenario there seems to be a growing divergence from close to not very close in your results.

Comment: What is the recommended time to leave a question open?